# Flutter Ripple effect color

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How can I change ripple effect color in Flutter?

Comment: i did, but I am not currently infront of my PC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap your widget in `Theme` and provide the `data` as

```
data: ThemeData(splashColor: Colors.red)
```

Comment: seems that it doesn't cover buttons, you have to add `splashColor` also to the `buttonTheme` in your ThemeData

Answer (score 5):

An example for the @CopsOnRoad's answer. (Like-Button)

```
Theme(
   data: ThemeData(splashColor: Colors.red[200]),
   child: Material(
       elevation: 0,
       shape: CircleBorder(),
       clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
       color: Colors.transparent,
       child: InkWell(
       child: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Icon(
                   Icons.favorite,
                   color: _isLiked ? Colors.red : Colors.black12,
                   size: 20,
                      ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                    if(_isLiked){
                        setState(() {
                           _isLiked = false;
                           //You backend state manage code
                        });
                    }else{
                        setState(() {
                           _isLiked = true;
                           //You backend state manage code
                        });
                    }
                },
          ),
    ),
)
```

[image]